# Can I convert a BlobContainerClient to String?

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage

So, I'm returning a BlobContainerClient and using this value on another method.
But in this method I passed a string parameter, because I need a string.

How I can convert a blob container client to string for don't change my method?

Comment: What do you mean, can you post the code of the method accepting a string? Because it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, `BlobContainerClient` cannot be converted to `String` type, and there is no inheritance or interface implementation relationship between these two classes.

The `BlobContainerClient` object is mainly used to obtain the `BlobClient` object. If it is forced to be converted to the `String` type, it will not be obtained normally, and an error will be reported if it is forced to transfer.

So, if I understand correctly, you may need to change the parameter of your method.

You can refer to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) of the `BlobContainerClient` class to help you understand it better.

This official document is about the [usage example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#object-model) of `BlobContainerClient`.

If I misunderstood or you have any other questions, please let me know.